# Files move from one library to another library using jsom

Tags: javascript, csom, jsom, sharepoint-library

Below code is working fine, but inside for-loop if I put alert,then moving multiple file but if I remove, only one file moving.

I do not want any alert/pop up. Please suggest.

```
        <Groups Id="Ribbon.MoveFiles.Groups">
          <Group
          Id="Ribbon.MoveFiles.MoveFilesCustomGroup"
          Description="This is a EMC group!"
          Sequence="52"
           Title="Move Files From Draft To Client"
          Template="Ribbon.Templates.EMCCustomTemplateLayout">
            <Controls Id="Ribbon.MoveFiles.MoveFilesCustomGroup.Controls">
              <Button
              Id="Ribbon.MoveFiles.MoveFilesCustomGroup.MoveFilesDoc"
              Command="MoveFiles.MoveFilesDoc"
              Sequence="17"

              LabelText="Move selected files – Draft to Client"
              Image32by32="/Style Library/petronas/images/Archive.png"

              TemplateAlias="cust2"/>

            </Controls>
          </Group>
        </Groups>
      </Tab>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
      <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.FilesMoveTemplateLayout">
        <Layout
        Title="OneLargeTwoMedium"
        LayoutTitle="OneLargeTwoMedium">
          <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
            <Row>
              <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust1" />
            </Row>
          </Section>
          <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
            <Row>
              <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust2" />
            </Row>

          </Section>
        </Layout>
      </GroupTemplate>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>

  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
     Command="MoveFiles.MoveFilesDoc"
    CommandAction="javascript:
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
            context.load(web);
            var _destinationlib = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Client (Final) Folder');              
            context.load(_destinationlib);


            var notifyId;               
             var currentlibid = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
            var currentLib = web.get_lists().getById(currentlibid);  

            var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
            var count = CountDictionary(selectedItems);

            if(count==0){
            alert('Please choose at least  one file to move from Draft Folder.');
            }
            for(var i in selectedItems)
            {

                var currentItem = currentLib.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
                context.load(currentItem);
                var File = currentItem.get_file();
                context.load(File);
                //Excecuting executeQueryAsync to get the loaded values        

                context.executeQueryAsync
                    (
                        function (sender, args) {

                            if(File != null) {
                                var _destinationlibUrl =  web.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '/' +  'Documents' +  '/' + File.get_name();
                               // alert('File destination Now moving to: ' + _destinationlibUrl);
                                File.moveTo(_destinationlibUrl, 1);
                                notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Moving file ' + File.get_serverRelativeUrl() + ' to ' + _destinationlibUrl, true);
                                //Excecuting executeQueryAsync to copy the file
                                context.executeQueryAsync(
                                    function (sender, args) {
                                        SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
                                        SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('File moved successfully', false);
                                    },
                                    function (sender, args) {
                                        SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Error moving file: ' + args.get_message(), false);
                                        SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);

                                });
                            }
                        },
                        function (sender, args) {
                            alert('Error occured' + args.get_message());
                        }
                    );
            }"/>

  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Can you add explain it more?

Comment: The trick is to avoid making any asynchronous calls from within in a loop. Refer to Viraj's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   var files = [];
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web(); context.load(web);
   var _destinationlib = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Client (Final) Folder');
   context.load(_destinationlib);
   var notifyId;
   var currentlibid = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
   var currentLib = web.get_lists().getById(currentlibid);
   var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
   var count = CountDictionary(selectedItems);
   if (count == 0)
   {
       alert('Please choose at least  one file to move from Draft Folder.');
   }
   for (var i in selectedItems)
   {
       var currentItem = currentLib.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
       context.load(currentItem); var fle = currentItem.get_file();

       files.push(fle);
       context.load(fle);
   }
   context.executeQueryAsync(
       function (sender, args)
       {
           for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
           {
               var File = files[i];
               if (File != null)
               {
                   var _destinationlibUrl = web.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '/' + 'Documents' + '/' + File.get_name(); File.moveTo(_destinationlibUrl, 1);
                   notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Moving file ' + File.get_serverRelativeUrl() + ' to ' + _destinationlibUrl, true);
                   context.executeQueryAsync(
                       function (sender, args)
                       {
                           SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId); SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('File moved successfully', false);
                       },
                       function (sender, args) {
                            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Error moving file: ' + args.get_message(), false);
                            SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
                   });
               }
           }
       }, function (sender, args) {
           alert('Error occured' + args.get_message());
  });
```