# executeQueryAsync function calling not working using for loop

Tags: client-object-model, caml-query, jsom

I am having values in result[15452,33616] when using for loop ,the async function taking only last array value (e.g-33616) and fetching the data for that pushing to another array and final push into grid.for array[0] (e.g -15452)values data is not fetching . & it is repeating the same row three times for 33616.Please reply as soon as earlier.Need of urgent.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        {
            var isFirst = 1;
            var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var lists = context.get_web().get_lists();
            var associatedProjectsList = lists.getByTitle('Master Project Data');
            var camlQueryAssociatedProjects = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQueryAssociatedProjects.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID"/><Value Type="Number">'
            + result[i]["ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookupId"] + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
            associatedProjectsItems = associatedProjectsList.getItems(camlQueryAssociatedProjects);
            context.load(associatedProjectsItems);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                MPDS = MasterProjectDataSuccess();
                if (isFirst == 1) {
                    rfaarr = MPDS;
                    isFirst = 0;
                }
                else {

                    rfaarr = $.extend(rfaarr, MPDS);
                    inputoJGrid.push(rfaarr);
                    self.PushToGrid(inputoJGrid);
                }
            }, MasterProjectDataFailure);


            var lists1 = context.get_web().get_lists();
            var associatedProjectsList1 = lists1.getByTitle('Project Users');
            var camlQueryAssociatedProjects1 = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQueryAssociatedProjects1.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID"/><Value Type="Number">'
            + result[i]["ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookupId"] + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
            associatedProjectsItems1 = associatedProjectsList1.getItems(camlQueryAssociatedProjects1);
            context.load(associatedProjectsItems1);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                PUS = ProjectUsersSuccess();
                if (isFirst == 1) {
                    rfaarr = PUS;
                    isFirst = 0;
                }
                else {
                    rfaarr = $.extend(rfaarr, PUS);
                    inputoJGrid.push(rfaarr);
                    self.PushToGrid(inputoJGrid);
                }
            }, ProjectUsersFailure);
        }
    });
};
function MasterProjectDataSuccess() {
    var listItemEnumerator = associatedProjectsItems.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var cur = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        rfalistfetch["ProjectTitle"] = cur.get_item("ESI_ProjectName");
        rfalistfetch["SequenceNo"] = cur.get_item("ESI_ProjectSequenceNo");
        rfalistfetch["Division"] = cur.get_item("ESI_Division").get_lookupValue();
        rfalistfetch["SubDivision"] = cur.get_item("ESI_SubDivision").get_lookupValue();
        rfalistfetch["Status"] = cur.get_item("ESI_Status").get_lookupValue();
        rfalistfetch["ProjectType"] = cur.get_item("ESI_ProjectCategory").get_lookupValue();
        var Budget = cur.get_item("ESI_BudgetYear");
        var dutyDateObj = new Date(Budget);
        var day = "" + dutyDateObj.getDate();
        if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + day;
        }
        var month = "" + (dutyDateObj.getMonth() + 1);
        if (month.length == 1) {
        month = "0" + month;
        }
        var year = "" + (dutyDateObj.getYear() + 1);
        if (year.length == 1) {
        year = "0" + year;
        }
        rfalistfetch["BudgetYear"] = dutyDateObj.getFullYear();
        rfalistfetch["BMP"] = cur.get_item("ESI_BeginningMP");
        rfalistfetch["EMP"] = cur.get_item("ESI_EndingMP");
        rfalistfetch["State"] = cur.get_item("ESI_State").get_lookupValue();
        rfalistfetch["Station"] = cur.get_item("ESI_Station");
        rfalistfetch["SubCategory"] = cur.get_item("ESI_SubCategory").get_lookupValue();
        rfalistfetch["LineSegment"] = cur.get_item("ESI_LineSegment");
        rfalistfetch["DOT"] = cur.get_item("ESI_DOTNumber");
        rfalistfetch["BriefScope"] = cur.get_item("ESI_BriefScope");
        rfalistfetch["CPAR"] = cur.get_item("ESI_CPAR");
        rfalistfetch["ProjectID"] = cur.get_item("ID").toString();
        return rfalistfetch;
    }
};

function ProjectUsersSuccess() {
    var listItemEnumerator1 = associatedProjectsItems1.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator1.moveNext()) {       
        var curr = listItemEnumerator1.get_current();
        rfalistfetch["ESDirector"] = curr.get_item("ESI_Director").get_lookupValue();
        return rfalistfetch;
    }
};
```

Comment: Asking your question a second time will not help with your credit rate

Answer (score 0):

I have answered on this question:
[Files move from one library to another library using jsom](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176511/files-move-from-one-library-to-another-library-using-jsom/176635#176635)

1. Here i have set array globally.
2. Push and load the item one by one in array with Looping of
   itemcollection
3. Get array result in executeQueryAsync-success function

Comment: If I get your paycheck I can do your work

Comment: I can't update your code. I can give the solution or suggestion. Try to understand the code with here i have written steps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using executeQueryAsync method of SharePoint it will process the request aysnchronously. Have a look at jquery Deferred variable to control your aynchronous operations.

Sample code:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
queryList(i).done(function(resultArr)
{
MasterProjectDataSuccess();
}) 
.fail(function(){
MasterProjectDataFailure();
})
}
```

Comment: where i have to use this deferred in my code/?

Comment: No need to include confusing deferred here. Not to mention he has to include jQuery as well. JavaScript has native promises now which can be ployfilled easily

Comment: can you explain how to do?

Comment: @Akhoy thanks for the info.

Look into the following link for usage of javascript promise
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: Thanks for the info,But this how i implement in my code ,I am using for loop how it will works